# How to identify if an ec2 instance is part of Autoscaling group using .net aws sdk ?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

DescribeInstance return both manually created EC2 instance and EC2 instance created by auto scaling launch configuration . how to identify particular instance is part of autoscaling group?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show your code, please. StackOverflow is not a code writing service or an advice forum, we need to see your code so we can help you fix it.

Comment: EC2 instances that are part of an auto scaling group have a tag called aws:autoscaling:groupName. Tags starting with "aws:" are created by AWS.

Answer (score 0):

If an EC2 instance is part of any AutoScalingGroup it automatically receives a tag with the key "aws:autoscaling:groupName" and the value with the name of the associate AutoScaling.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/ec2-auto-scaling-tagging.html